# java.lang.NullPointerException at Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am quite new to Java and Android programming, and just working on my 3rd App - however I am encountering a Problem which I am not able to solve (I already tried and researched for days).

I have a list of Elements in a LinearLayout inside a Fragment - the Elements have a OnLongClickListener attached, with a popup showing up when the User long-presses the Element. That works fine. However, one of the Buttons in the Popup is "Edit", and when a user presses this Button, I want to start another Activity with Editing Options for this Element.

So there comes my Problem: when I want to start the new Activity with an Intent, I get following Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
        at at.fekle.zipmanager.start.startzipinfo(start.java:299)
        at at.fekle.zipmanager.start$2.onLongClick(start.java:277)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4247)
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:17341)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But, if i start the same Activity with the same Intent from a simple Button defined in the Layout, the Activity Starts fine without any Errors... weird, isn't it?

So, does anyone have an Idea how I can solve this problem?

Here are some extractions from my code:

**The Creation of the Elements with the OnLongClickListener:**

```
ScrollView parent = (ScrollView) maininflater.inflate(R.layout.start_ziplist_fragment_superwrapper, null, false);
    inf = maininflater;
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) maininflater.inflate(R.layout.start_ziplist_fragment_wrapper, parent, false);

    for (Integer i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ArrayList<String> data = new DB(cont).getAllZips().get(i);
        View custom = maininflater.inflate(R.layout.start_ziplist_fragment_inner, ll, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.ziplist_name);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.ziplist_text);
        tv.setText(data.get(2));
        tv2.setText(data.get(1));
        Integer id =  Integer.valueOf(data.get(0));
        custom.setId(id);

        custom.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Integer id = view.getId();
                startzipinfo(id);
                return true;
            }
        });

        ll.addView(custom);
    }
    parent.addView(ll);
```

**The void which starts the Activity:**

```
public void startzipinfo(Integer id){
    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), zipinfo.class);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

I'm looking forward to your Answers,

Felix

**EDIT: This is the Activity which is about to be started:**

```
package at.fekle.zipmanager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by felix on 27.06.13.
 */
public class zipinfo extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.zipinfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: are You sure that ArrayList<String> data is not null? Maybe You cannot get the data from database for any reason

Comment: post your zipinfo.class. because error can occur in this files too.

Comment: the data is fine, my list gets filled with the data from the database, no problem there ;)

Comment: Is this your complete stacktrace?

Comment: @Nirmal

OK, I'll do that

Comment: that's look fine post your full code.

Comment: have you get data from intent that u started? getting from extras

Comment: Nope, had it in the code, but removed it because I thought this may cause the problem, but it wasn't the problem...

Comment: could you add which android version you are running your app on?

Comment: @baske 
Android 4.2.2 JellyBean on a Nexus 4 ;-)

Comment: Ok.. then I am looking through the correct version's source code.. The line at which the NullPointerException is thrown (line 3370 of Activity.java) leaves only a few options for your error: either Activity's mInstrumentation or mMainThread members are null.. These variables are both set when your Activity is attached to the Window (assuming you are not running a UnitTest?). It seems weird to me that you get errors like this. I dug a bit deeper, but at the places where the window is attached you should have already gotten a RuntimeException if one of these variables was 'null'.. Odd..

Comment: As I am not wrong, You set an value from "data" to Your View as id, so what exactly is this "data" ArrayList<String>. Which Content is inside this list?

Comment: Maybe it will be better to use "setTag(yourTagInteger)" instead of setId

Comment: this "data" is an ID from a Database entry for further use - however if I replace the setID with setTag, or remove the part with the data complete, the problem still exists with the exact same error :-(

Comment: I just tried the same in another application, and I got the exact same error :/

Comment: @baske

Yeah, weird, isn't it? However, I don't really know what a UnitTest is - I am running the application by clicking the "Play" icon in Android Studio, then the App is compiled and started on my Nexus 4 - so I don't think this is a UnitTest?

Comment: No, in that case it isn't.. For it to be a UnitTest you would have to create something like an ActivityTestCase and run the tests.

Comment: I don't know how to start a chat and invite you for that session, so I will try to give you some debugging steps I would now take if I could reproduce the problem: (a) Install the 4.2.2 sources using the sdk manager. (b) Set a breakpoint in your startzipinfo method. (c) Use "step into" and/or "step over" to get to Activity.java, line 3370 (where your NPE occurs) and print the values of all the relevant variables on that line to see which one is null. Continue analyzing why that is the case.. Sry I cannot be of more help.

Comment: @baske
Thanks again for your nice help! I just added breakpoints to inspect the variables - and I noticed one big difference. When starting the Activity via the simple Button, the variable "this" is full of data - however when starting it via the OnLongClick method, "this" is nearly empty, and the Application crashes. Any Idea what the cause of the Problem could be?

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you should tell me to which "this" variable you are referring ;-) "this" is used all over the place, so I need to know on which line of which file your are printing the contents if the "this" pointer. Is it at line 3370 of Activity.java? If that is what you mean, then what are the values of "this.mInstrumentation" and "this.mMainThread"?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use *YourActivityName*.this instead of getApplicationContext() :

```
public void startzipinfo(Integer id){
    Intent in = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, zipinfo.class);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your new intent class is mentioned in android manifest file if it does not exists then type:`<activity name=".YourClassName>
</activity>`

Comment: But he said it starts some times, but not every time

Comment: Yes, it is included :-) Like @Plato said, it starts with a normal button, the problem only exists when starting the activity from the LongClickListener...

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem!

I had to start the activity from the parent Fragment (passed to the method by the FragmentManager) - now everything works like a charm :)

```
custom.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    Integer id = view.getId();
                    id = 2;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(cont, zipinfo.class);
                    fragment.startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Thanks for all answers!

Cheers,

Felix

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. can you please elaborate this.  what is the variable fragment? can u show its declaration too, it will be helpfull